# What happens to related fields when I archive a record?

Tags: python, odoo, archive

Odoo - All versions

When a record is archived, all the relational fields are lost. When I again make the record active, the relational records are shown again.

What happens to those foreign keys ?? Is it possible to get the relational records when it is still inactive ? Also, is it possible to overwrite archive functionality. If yes, how ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The archiving-feature is based on a simple boolean field, which is used to filter out from display:

```
  class BlogPost(models.Model):
     _inherit = 'blog.post'
     active = fields.Boolean(string='Active', default=True)
```

The record field: "active" will change when it's toggled but the corresponding record and its relations remain unchanged.

The underlying code corresponding to the filtering can be found in the file src/odoo/odoo/models.py :

```
 class MetaModel(api.Meta):
 """ The metaclass of all model classes.
    Its main purpose is to register the models per module.
 """
    def action_archive(self):
        """
        Set active=False on a recordset, by calling toggle_active 
        to take the corresponding actions according to the model
        """
       return self.filtered(lambda record: record.active).toggle_active()

    @api.model
    def _where_calc(self, domain, active_test=True):
       """Computes the WHERE clause needed to implement an OpenERP domain.
       :param domain: the domain to compute
       :type domain: list
       :param active_test: whether the default filtering of 
        records with ``active`` field set to ``False`` should be 
       applied.
       :return: the query expressing the given domain as provided in domain
      :rtype: osv.query.Query
      """
      # if the object has a field named 'active', filter out all inactive
      # records unless they were explicitely asked for
      if 'active' in self._fields and active_test and self._context.get('active_test', True):
        # the item[0] trick below works for domain items and '&'/'|'/'!'
        # operators too
          if not any(item[0] == 'active' for item in domain):
            domain = [('active', '=', 1)] + domain

          if domain:
            e = expression.expression(domain, self)
            tables = e.get_tables()
            where_clause, where_params = e.to_sql()
            where_clause = [where_clause] if where_clause else []
          else:
             where_clause, where_params, tables = [], [], ['"%s"' 
             % self._table]

          return Query(tables, where_clause, where_params)
```

To display all records (archived and active):

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'blog'
    post_ids = fields.One2many(
        'blog.post', 'id', 
         domain=['|', ('active', '=', True), ('active', '=', False)],
        context={'active_test': False})
```

Comment: seems active_test=True is the arg.. which can be used to access archived records.

Comment: But still I could not figure out a way to access many2one relations/related records of archived record. It is not there in db itself. For eg: from an archived product(product_template) you cannot access related product.product values.

Comment: In the UI (user interface): You can use the standard list view of your records (for instance : /web#action=309&model=product.template&view_type=list&cids=1&menu_id=185) , and then in "Filter" > click on "Archived"

Comment: ...Or, by using Code : class Blog(models.Model):
    post_ids = fields.One2many(
        'blog.post', 'id', 
         domain=['|', ('active', '=', True), ('active', '=', False)],
        context={'active_test': False})